# Looking for quantum-resistant cryptography package for Flutter/Dart

Tags: api, cryptography, dart, flutter

I recall seeing some sort of potential quantum-resistant cryptographic algorithm in a Flutter package API however I have searched and searched again and cannot find anything.

Anyone know of any Flutter/Dart quantum-resistant crypto package?

Comment: Are you searching for symmetric or asymmetric ciphers?

Comment: Either really, with symmetric data can be encrypted and with asymmetric keys can be encrypted. That is if the same cypher block lengths apply to quantum-resistant crypto.

Comment: I am not sure if you really understand cryptography as to my knowledge there are no asymmetric block ciphers.

Comment: Их практически нет на dart, в основном на более популярных языках или на dart можно написать самому, но всеже одна есть для тебя ))) https://github.com/AldrinMathew/kyber.dart/tree/main/lib

Answer (score 0):

There are practically no them on darts, mostly in more popular countries or on darts you can write it yourself, but still there is one for you)))https://github.com/AldrinMathew/kyber.dart/tree/main/lib

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is it...

Closest I could find - someone has done it already. Havent tested or verified it:

[Quantum resistant Dart - Javascript algo](https://medium.com/@mundorap2010/crystals-kyber-flutter-js-a8fa755a0f0c)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).